# LocalBroadcastManager don't receive broadcast on 2.3

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice, localbroadcastmanager

Not works on 2.3. But works on 4.0.x. Why?

**Sending from IntentService:**

```
intent.setAction(MessagesThread.NEW_MESSAGE);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**Receiving**

```
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,new IntentFilter(NEW_MESSAGE));
}

protected void onStop() {
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
super.onStop();
}

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    .......................................
            .......................................
}
};
```

Comment: where do you register the receiver and when do you send the broadcast?

Comment: Need to register in manifest?

Comment: Which version of android.support.v4.jar are you using that implements LocalBroadcastManager for android2.3? Is your intendserrvice "within your process."?

Comment: no, you dont need to register in manifest but the order matters

Comment: android.support.v4.jar revision 20

Comment: In manifest: <service android:name="com.sakh.main.GcmIntentService" />

Comment: are you registering the receiver in an activity? do you send the broadcast after the receiver is registered?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but the issue might be due to LocalBroadcastManager. Try sending broadcast without using LocalBroadcastManager, like below:

SEND BROADCAST

```
Intent i = new Intent("ALERT_CHANGE");
i.putExtra("DATA","News");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

RECEIVE BROADCAST-in Activity

```
registerReceiver(uiUpdated, new IntentFilter("ALERT_CHANGE"));


private BroadcastReceiver uiUpdated= new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
String DATA = i.getStringExtra("Data");
txt.settext(DATA);
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(newIntent(MessagesThread.NEW_MESSAGE).putExtras(intent));
```